# System clipboard is flushed out, once I exit vim

Tags: x11, vim, clipboard

I use `yy` to access the system clipboard always. `yy` is mapped to a function as,

```
function! Copy_ToSystemClip()
  .w !xsel -ob
end function

inoremap yy Copy_ToSystemClip()<CR>
```

It copies to the system clipboard. The contents are available, as long as the vim process is alive.

Once I quit vim, and try to paste the same contents in shell terminal, the clipboard contents are thrown out and the contents are lost.

Since I use vim inside bash, I can't copy to bash while keeping vim window open.

How can I ensure, that clipboard contents stay even when vim dies?

Comment: First: is your code the one you actually use? Because your mapping as you show it doesn't work (it simply add the name of the function to your buffer). Second: I can't reproduce your problem. I replaced your mapping with `inoremap yy <Esc>:Copy_ToSystemClip()<CR>i` to be as close as possible as what I think you want to do and then the yanked content stays in the clipboard even after vim is closed. Have you tried to put your function and mapping in a file `foo.vimrc` and start vim with `vim -u foo.vimrc` to be sure that the problem doesn't come from another part of your vimrc?

Comment: Solution to this problem: https://superuser.com/questions/299419/prevent-vim-from-clearing-the-clipboard-on-exit